# VAST/VPAID tag ssp

Tags: vast

I have VAST/VPAID tag. According to the documentation http://www.iab.net/media/file/OpenRTBAPISpecificationVersion2_2.pdf type of the tag indicates by video object in line 'api'. If in all bid request 'api' is empty. How do you know that the player supports vpaid?
Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple, SSP just do not support the VPAID.